# How to predict the time complexity of matrix multiplication and inverse on a GPU?

Tags: computer-architecture, parallel-computing, matrix

Nvidia GPU can speed up the matrix manipulation greatly. I want to have a basic idea to predict the consumed time for matrix manipulation.

How can I analyze the time complexity of matrix multiplication and inverse operation on a GPU?

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: Why guess when you can run an experiment?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I run some experiments [https://stackoverflow.com/q/61535710/7672954], it is hard to get the theoretical support from experiments